# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in react JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA5Me.jpg)

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div className="container my-3">
            <h2 id="swea">News 24/7 - Top '{this.capitalizeFirstletter(this.props.category)}' Headlines </h2>

            {this.state.loading && <Spinner />}

            <div className='rows'>
                {!this.state.loading && this.state.article.map((element) => {
                    return <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
                        <NewsItem title={element.title ? element.title.slice(0, 90) : ""} description={element.description ? element.description.slice(0, 50) : ""} imageUrl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url} author={element.author} date={element.publishedAt} source={element.source.name} />
                    </div>
                })}
            </div>

            <div className="container d-flex justify-content-between">
                <button type="button" disabled={this.state.page <= 1} className="btn btn-dark" onClick={this.handlePrevClick} >&larr; Previous</button>
                <button type="button" disabled={this.state.page + 1 > Math.ceil(this.state.totalResults / this.props.pageSize)} id="xxx" className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleNextClick} >Next &rarr;</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

}

*Here's the error**

Comment: check the values in articles variable

Comment: which are the values

Comment: I mean check the data inside `this.state.articles` state variable and check whether it is an array or not

Answer (score 0):

Before mapping over this.state.article first check if the state variable is empty. For example:

```
this.state.article.length?this.state.article.map((item)=>{return item}):null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like cyber said, I was getting through the problem for almost an hour and finally I found the problem is empty variable. I didn't return the result and made my array empty, then I continue get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')".Please check your variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).